# GWT historyFrame causes a blank line in the body part

Tags: html, css, gwt

I want to use the preferred `<!doctype html>` in my GWT index.html and I also want to make use of the (hidden) `__gwt_historyFrame` iframe.
But when I use both the `<body>` starts with a blank line.
This code below will show what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: green;
        }
        #container {
            width: inherit;
            height: inherit;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: pink;
        }
        h1 {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
     <iframe src="javascript:''" 
             id="__gwt_historyFrame" 
             style="width:0;height:0;border:0;">
    </iframe>
    <div id="container">
        Green bar above..
    </div>
</body>
```

This code will show a pink page with a green bar at the top. The height of the bar is dependent of the font-size defined for the body tag.
Does anyone know how I can circumvent this problem, besides using a `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">` doctype?

Comment: Not an direct answer: is your app supporting IE6 and IE7? If not, then just remove the iframe.

Comment: According to the latest GWT documentation I have to embed the 'historyFrame' when I want to make use of the Browsers history.

Comment: Believe me, it's only required for IE6 and IE7. If you don't trust me, look at the code for the various `HistoryImpl`.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I'll believe you, it's just that I didn't see any hints on this at the GWT site. (Or I just missed them..:-/ ) Thanks for all the help!

Comment: We totally agree that the docs need some love; we'll be working on it soon (including accepting contributions from the community)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `position:absolute` in the `iframe` style and/or put it out of the viewport.

Comment: <iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" tabIndex="-1" style="position:absolute;width:0;height:0;border:0;"></iframe> did the tric! Thanks Andrea!